# How to enforce Kotlin "when" covers all possible options?

Tags: kotlin

I've found out that, surprisingly, Kotlin's when expression does not enforce handling all possible options if its result is not assigned.

This example compiles:

```
import Options.*

fun main() {
    print(Options.Great)
    print(Options.Medium)
    print(Options.TooLittle("needs more"))
}

fun print(opts: Options) {
    when (opts) {
//        Great -> println("It's great")
        Medium -> println("It's so so...")
        is TooLittle -> println("It's not enough because: ${opts.reason}")
    }
}

sealed class Options {
    object Great: Options()
    object Medium: Options()
    data class TooLittle(val reason: String): Options()    
}
```

And prints:

```
It's so so...
It's not enough because: needs more
```

Notice it's missing one case.

I've been assigning the result of the `when` expression to a non-used variable just to enforce comprehensibility...

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE") val ignore = when(...) ...
```

The example above doesn't compile if the commented-out option is not uncommented, as I'd hoped it would do by default.

Is there a better way to achieve that?

NOTE to mods: this is not a duplicate of the question about forcing compilation error in sealed classes: my question is specifically about comprehensive when statements, which involves sealed classes, as in my example, but also can include other things like enums and types with a finite number of cases like `Boolean`.

Comment: This article suggests something https://blog.karumi.com/kotlin-android-development-6-months-into-it/

Comment: In this case, it's also technically enough to just `return when (...) {...}`. Returning works with a Unit return type, as well as other values, but assumes the function is done after the `when`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is that `when` is forced to cover all possible options if and only if it is an expression rather than a statement, that is, if it's in a position where its result value is somehow used.

One solution would be to assign the result to a variable, but this would lead to an unused variable warning:

```kotlin
val coverAllOptions = when (opts) {
    Great -> println("It's great")
    Medium -> println("It's so so...")
    is TooLittle -> println("It's not enough because: ${opts.reason}")
}
```

Another option that could work but leads to an IDE warning as well is to add a cast `as Unit` after the `when` statement.

Another solution that I personally prefer is to add some function call after the `when`'s closing curly brace. It may be a meaningless call, such as `let`, `apply` or `run` with a lambda that is empty and only contains a comment documenting the purpose:

```kotlin
when (opts) {
    Great -> println("It's great")
    Medium -> println("It's so so...")
    is TooLittle -> println("It's not enough because: ${opts.reason}")
}.run { /* cover all options */ }
```

As in the [article](https://blog.karumi.com/kotlin-android-development-6-months-into-it/) suggested by [@al3c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6962183/al3c), if you need this often, you may create an extension function or an extension property that doesn't do anything and is only used to append it to `when` expressions:

```kotlin
val Any?.exhaustive get() = Unit
```

```kotlin
when (opts) {
    Great -> println("It's great")
    Medium -> println("It's so so...")
    is TooLittle -> println("It's not enough because: ${opts.reason}")
}.exhaustive
```